# C++ mulitple definitions of function when compiling for multiple architectures

Tags: c++, cross-platform, header-files

I have 4 files, `linuxasm.h linuxasm.cpp windowsasm.h and windowsasm.cpp`

in the main.cpp i have

```
#ifdef __linux
  #include "linuxasm.h"
#elif _WIN64
  #include "winasm.h"
#endif
```

the function names in the .cpps are identical
is there a way to prevent GCC from complaining about multiple definitions of functions?
Or should I go about it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it some other way.  I would use your build system to omit the appropriate .cpp file from the build based on architecture (if I understand your situation correctly).

Basically, for one target, say Win64, the windowsasm.cpp is a dependency and is compiled; similarly for Linux. Look up how your system is managing dependencies for the build and give it a try.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? sorry this is the first time I have made a cross platform program.  I am using codeblocks if it helps

Comment: Vaguely familiar with codeblocks-- does it use makefiles underneath?  Basically, for one target, say Win64, the windowsasm.cpp is a dependency and is compiled; similarly for Linux.  Look up how your system is managing dependencies for the build.  HTH!